# Peripheral accelerometer attached to Android phone

Tags: android, android-ndk, linux-kernel, accelerometer

I am doing an experiment with Android smartphone and accelerometer to detect some values. Due to the limitation of positioning of cellphone, I intend to use a peripheral accelerometer sensor instead of the internal Android smartphone sensor.

Are there any peripheral accelerometer sensors that can be used to collect data and sent to the Android phone in real-time via some kind of communication (better wireless, e.g. Bluetooth).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically you can use any peripheral device which has a Linux driver for it. You will have  to compile a custom kernel for your phone with this driver enabled and included.

Note that to install a custom kernel you will have to root your phone, which would void its warranty.